# Diferencia entre numpy.empty y numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

`np.empty` se considera un vector basura en el que sirve para saber que tipo de datos contiene el vector y un `np.array` devuelve una matriz, pero en qué caso es más conveniente utilizar cada uno de ellos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero de todo hay que tener en cuenta que ambos métodos retornan un array de NumPy, concretamente un objeto `numpy.ndarray`.

[**`numpy.empty`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) crea un array del tamaño y tipo de dato especificado (si no se especifica, el tipo será `float` por defecto) reservando el espacio necesario en memoria para él. Lo más importante a tener en cuenta es que **no inicializa el array**, es decir, el valor de sus elementos es indeterminado al contener "valores basura". El valor de sus elementos son el resultado de lo que ha habido antes almacenado en esa parte de la RAM (porque fue usada por otro programa, resultado del chequeo de hardware durante el POST, etc).

No inicializar el array tiene como ventaja evitar la pequeña sobrecarga que implica inicializar todos y cada uno de los elementos a un valor dado, como puede ser `0` en un array de enteros. Pero lo anterior no suele justificar esta práctica porque tiene un gran inconveniente, si no recorremos posteriormente el array completamente dándole valores oportunos a cada elemento, podemos tener **resultados inesperados** si operamos con estas posiciones por error.

Un ejemplo:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.empty(4, dtype = int)
>>> arr[0] = 2
>>> arr[1] = 4
>>> arr[2] = 1
>>> sum(arr)
504
```

2 + 4 + 1 = ¿504? Aunque en este ejemplo estúpido pueda ser fácil de ver el problema, en códigos complejos nos podemos encontrar con errores difíciles de rastrear, o lo que es peor, que obtengamos resultados erróneos que pasen desapercibidos en un principio. La causa es simple, nos "olvidamos" de asignar un valor al último elemento del array y cuando declaramos nuestro array este no se inicializa, por lo que vete a saber que contiene en dicha posición:

```
>>> arr = np.empty(4, dtype = int)
>>> arr
array([120313928, 497, 54957592, 497])
```

Por norma general, es una buena práctica inicializar el array, y si no se hace, hay que ser muy **cuidadosos en su manejo y estar absolutamente seguros** de que vamos a rellenar todos los elementos con valores adecuados. Podemos usar [`numpy.zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros)/`numpy.zeros_like` (inicializa todos los valores a 0), [`numpy.one`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html#numpy.ones)/`numpy.one_like` (inicializa todos los valores a 1) o [`numpy.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html)/`numpy.full_like` (inicializa a un valor dado).

---

Los métodos anteriores son usados cuando queremos crear un array para operar con él, pero no tenemos a priori valores iniciales para llenarlo.
[**`numpy.array`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) en cambio nos permite construir un array con datos previos conocidos a partir de cualquier objeto similar ("array-like") como una lista, una tupla, otro array, etc. Por lo tanto lo normal es usarlo **cuando conocemos los valores iniciales del array**.